# Temp table not dropping from DB

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a large query that starts by selecting into #tmp1.  Before that select statement I have the following:

```
USE Sandbox

--if the table exists, we want to delete it first
IF (EXISTS (SELECT * 
                 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' 
                 AND  TABLE_NAME = '#tmp1'))
BEGIN
    drop table dbo.#tmp1
END
```

The problem is that when I run the entire query I get an **error:**

```
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 51
There is already an object named '#tmp1' in the database.
```

If I highlight the above statement and run it I get:

`Command(s) completed successfully.`

But if I run the query again, I get the error above.

I have also tried these two (with 'completed successfully' as the result and I still get the error above when trying to run the **query:**

```
if exists (select * from sys.objects where name = '#tmp1' and type = 'u')
    drop table dbo.#tmp1

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.#tmp1', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE dbo.#tmp1
```

Can anyone see what I may be doing wrong?

I use a total of 4 temp tables, my large SQL statement is structured like this:

```
USE Sandbox

If #tmp1 exists, drop it    
If #tmp2 exists, drop it    
If #tmp3 exists, drop it   
If #tmp4 exists, drop it

Declare variables

select into #tmp1    
select into #tmp2    
select into #tmp3    
select into #tmp4    
select from #tmp1    
select from #tmp2    
select from #tmp3    
select from #tmp4
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Temp tables live in `tempdb`... but your current code is checking for the object to exist in your `Sandbox` database.

Change your code to use a 3-part name, including the database, `tempdb`, where the temporary table lives:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#tmp1', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE dbo.#tmp1
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought it was something simple.  I couldn't figure out why this statement worked with other tables and not tempdb...I learned a little something today.